# Compute $\mathbb{E}\left(W_s^2\left(\int_s^t W_r d W_r\right)^2\right)$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, brownian-motion

Let $W=\left(\Omega, \mathcal{F},\left(\mathcal{F}_t\right)_{t \geq 0},\left(W_t\right)_{t \geq 0}, \mathbb{P}\right)$ be a Brownian motion.
I have tried the following, see photo.
[image]

The simulation code in R, is the following for anyone interested:

````
rm(list=ls())
library('e1071')
freq    = 10000
s <- 0.3
t <- 1
true <- numeric(2000)
means2 <- numeric(2000)
means3 <- numeric(2000)
for (i in 1:length(true)) {
  W  = rwiener(end = t, frequency = freq)
 
  true[i] = W[s*freq]^2 * sum( ( 1/freq) * (W[(s*freq):(t*freq)] )^2  )
                               
  means2[i] =  sum( ( 1/freq) * ( W[(s*freq):(t*freq)] - W[s*freq] )^2  )
  means3[i] = sum( ( 1/freq) *( (W[s*freq]-W[(s*freq):(t*freq)] )^2  ) )
}
mean(true)
(t-s)*3*s^2 + s*mean(means2)
(t-s)*3*s^2 + s*mean(means3)
((t-s)*3*s^2 + s*(t^2-s^2)/2 + (t-s)*s)/2
```
````

Comment: Please transcribe your screenshot to [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), also please give a more descriptive title

Comment: The Ito isometry says only $\mathbb E[(\int_s^t W_r\,dW_r)^2]=\mathbb E[\int_s^tW_r^2\,dr]$ without a factor $W_s^2$ in it. Write
$$
\int_s^tW_r\,dW_r=\frac{W_t^2-W_s^2-t+s}{2}
$$
square that and then expand everything that is in your first expectation.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you get that expression for the integral @KurtG.

Comment: @bast0320 That follows from applying Ito's formula to $W_t^2$.

Comment: Exactly. $W^2_t=2\int_0^tW_r\,dW_r+t\,.$ Now subtract the analogous expression for $W_s^2\,.$

Comment: I get: \begin{align} & \mathbb{E}\big(\frac{1}{4} W_s^6-\frac{1}{2} W_s^4 W_t^2-\frac{1}{2} W_s^4 s+\frac{1}{2} W_s^4 t \\ &+\frac{1}{4} W_s^2 W_t^4+\frac{1}{2} W_s^2 W_t^2 s-\frac{1}{2} W_s^2 W_t^2 t+\frac{1}{4} W_s^2 s^2-\frac{1}{2} W_s^2 s t+\frac{1}{4} W_s^2 t^2\big) \\ &=  \frac{s^3 \cdot 15}{4}-\frac{12 s^3+3 s^2 t}{2}-\frac{s \cdot 3 s^2}{2}+\frac{t 3 s^2}{2}+\frac{18 t^3-3 t^2 s}{4}+\frac{s \cdot\left(2 s^2+s t\right)}{2}-\frac{t \cdot\left(2 s^2+s t\right)}{2}+\frac{s^2 \cdot s}{4}-\frac{s^2 t}{2}+\frac{s t^2}{4} \\ &=  \frac{9}{2} t^3-\frac{s}{2} s^3-s^2 t-t^2 s .\end{align}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually somehow still "apply the conditional Ito isometry", if you use the Tower law, where you condition on $\mathcal{F}_s$, so you do get $E[\int_s^t W_s^2W_r^2dr]$, calculating this is now easy and you obtain the final answer $-(5/2)s^3 + st^2/2+2s^2t$, which is also what the simulation shows.